# HK2 does not see Spring Beans

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jersey-2.0, hk2

I have a Spring Boot application with Jersey 2 REST services.
Spring Boot seems to initialize correctly and I have Jersey Spring bridge ('org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-spring3:2.22.2').
Despite this the following error is thrown then REST controller (JAX-RS 2.0) is initialized and a Spring Bean have to be injected into it.

```
org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection
```

What can cause such error?

The bean is exist and annotated with @Named, so it is not the issue. Spring Boot by default scans for JSR-330 annotations too.

Edit:
initialization is done using:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
}
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Stacktrace:

```
DEBUG o.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder - An exception mapping did not successfully produce and processed a response. Logging the exception propagated to the container.
org.glassfish.hk2.api.MultiException: A MultiException has 3 exceptions.  They are:
1. org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=RequestEndEventLogger,parent=RequestEndEventController,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,125747480)
2. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of com.company.controller.RequestEndEventController errors were found
3. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on com.company.controller.RequestEndEventController

at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Collector.throwIfErrors(Collector.java:89)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:249)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:357)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:83)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:71)
at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:97)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:154)
at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:199)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:122)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2022)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:765)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:704)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:172)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:284)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:74)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:109)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:92)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:61)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:318)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:120)
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:61)
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:95)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:113)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2500)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2489)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=RequestEndEventLogger,parent=RequestEndEventController,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,125747480)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:75)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:211)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:234)
... 80 common frames omitted
```

The controller is:

```
@Named
@Singleton
@Path("/RequestEndEvent")
public class RequestEndEventController {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
    @Inject
    private RequestEndEventLogger logger;

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response sendRequestEndEvent(RequestEndEvent requestEndEvent) {
        logger.addRequestEndEvent(requestEndEvent);
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your `RequestEventLogger`? I can tell you that injecting Spring services into Jersey/HK2 resources/services isn't a problem with Spring Boot. How do you know that the logger is indeed in the Spring context? Have you tried to inject `ApplicationContext` and try to explicitly `ctx.getBean(RELogger.class)` to see if it's in the context?

Comment: @peeskillet You are right. I tried that you suggested and Spring is unable to find the class too. It is a simple class thought with \@Named annotation, so it should have been picked up by Spring.

Comment: What package is the logger in? It should be in the same package as the application class, or in a sub-package, for it to be picked up in the scan

Comment: @peeskillet That was the package issue. I moved application class one package up and suddenly everything works. Thanks a lot. Do you want to post an answer or I should rephrase the question first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual problem was something discovered in the comments (it was not shown in the original question).

With `@SpringBootApplication` (an alias for three annotations, including `@ComponentScan`), you get free component scan with Spring. But how component scan works (with out specifying packages to scan) is that it will scan the package of the `@ComponentScan` annotated class, and it's sub-packages. For this reason, it is recommended to put the "application" class in a root package, and have all the other packages as sub-packages of that package, e.g

```
com.app
   Application
com.app.services
   LoggingService
com.app.repos
   UserRepo
```

With this set up, all the packages get scanned for annotated components classes. I guess the OP did not have it set up this way, so the Spring components weren't getting picked up in the scan.

Comment: I am getting the same error but the fix doesn't work for me. I reshuffled the classes as stated in the solution here but I get the same error still. I have a similar configuration as stated in the question. Any assistance?

Comment: @AndyDufresne Post a new detailed question for better help

Comment: Apparently the error was because of dependency injection. The dependency wasn't injected because of which the above error got triggered. Thanks!